# Can't log events into application insights

Tags: c#, azure, logging, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to log some messages like error messages into app-insights using `ILogger`.

I have already implemented `ILogger` and it works fine for logging into Console, but it does not log anything into app-insights.
The [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#aspnet-core-applications) seems to be not up to date, since there is no method called `AddApplicationInsights` in `ILoggingBuilder` interface.

Therefore I've used the method `AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics` instead.

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {
                    // Add Azure Logging
                    logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                })
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

```
public class Startup
{
        private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

        public Startup(IConfiguration config, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            Configuration = config;
            _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
              ILogger logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<BasicBot>();

              logger.LogInformation("THAT IS A TEST MESSAGE");
        }
}
```

It logs fine into the Console BUT I see nothing in app-insights!

Hint: I'm using dotnet core 2.1 and debug in Development from visual studio.

Hint: app-insights works fine and logs the requests using `ITelemetry`. But I need `ILogger` too, to log different messages from many locations in the code!

Comment: Did you [add the Nuget package](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Application-Insights-for-ASP.NET-Core) and do all the setup?

Comment: yes, I did! app-insights works fine and logs the requests using `ITelemetry`. But I need `ILogger` too, to log different messages from many locations in the code!
I'll update the answer and add this info too!

Comment: I have used Serilog, configured to become the .net Core's ILogger implementation [like this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/samples/SimpleWebSample/Program.cs#L16)

Comment: @Taher, is this a .net core web application or console application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `AddApplicationInsights`  is included in this package [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights/).

I setup a .net core 2.1 web app, and configure application insight as well as installing this package [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights/) , version 2.9.1. The logs can be shown both in console and portal.

In code:

[image]

Test result - logs in azure portal:

[image]

Comment: but it has disabled the ITelemetry custom Middleware, which is injected by `AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics` method. When I added `AddApplicationInsights` method. Is using both of them not possible_

Comment: @Taher, I didn't use this method AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics before. Could you please pose a new issue and let me know the url? I'll investigate it.